# Concurrent transaction management in MS SqlServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have a question concerning transaction isolation in SQL Server. The default isolation level is set to 2 (READ_COMMITED). In the first transaction, I insert some data in table users; in the second, I try, unsuccessfully, to select all data from the same table, it seems that the second transaction waits for the first one to commit/rollback.

Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: What result are you hoping for?  A read that returns without waiting for the insert commit?  Do you want that read to contain the uncommitted rows?

Comment: I want to just read the data that already exists in the database.

Comment: What does "exists" mean to you? Exists, in this case, means it was committed. Why would you want uncommitted data? Take this example; I have a stored procedure with 2 insert commands inside one transaction. I insert the first, you then query the table and get that record, then when I go to insert the second, I get an error. The transaction rolls back but you still think that record is there.

Comment: You didn't understand my comment : 'Exists' means committed so I want to see the committed data. When I do my "select * from users' the transaction waits for the first one to finish. For me, it's a unexpected result.

Answer (score -1):

That is exactly what the read committed means, the second transaction will wait until it is able to read all the data. There are ways to either read the uncommitted data or skip it, but that is not something you would normally want to do.

There is quite a lot of material available for this, for example this one in [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc546518.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, I had a different understanding of READ-COMMITED : we will read just committed data, ie, in my case, I will read only committed rows without waiting for the other transaction to be finished. Otherwise, what is the difference between READ_COMMITTED and SERIALIZABLE?

Comment: To read only committed data and skip others, you'll need to use READPAST hint, but be careful when using those. The differences are listed for example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Comment: "Otherwise, what is the difference between READ_COMMITTED and SERIALIZABLE?" is not a question? Well at least I would consider that being one...

Comment: @Steve I was challenging his answer, not asking him a question. Read carefully!